# Duplicate and get the last item from the mysql table

Tags: mysql, database

table 1 `t1`

```
+----+----------+
| id |   name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | free     |
|  2 | basic    |
|  3 | advanced |
+----+----------+
```

table 2 `t2`

```
+----+-------+------+
| id | t1_fk | cost |
+----+-------+------+
|  1 |     2 | 1650 |
|  3 |     3 | 2000 |
|  4 |     2 |  550 |
+----+-------+------+
```

I want to get the output of t2 table but without duplicates. I was able to get this using `GROUP BY` function. Also i need the last item on the duplicate (i got stuck here).

Here's what i tried and it didn't work.

```
SELECT id cost FROM t2 GROUP BY t1_fk ORDER BY MAX(id) DESC
```

any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
     SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1_fk ORDER BY id DESC) rn
     FROM t2
)

SELECT id, t1_fk, cost
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, one canonical way to handle this would be to use a join to a subquery which finds the max `id` value for each `t1_fk`:

```
SELECT a.id, a.t1_fk, a.cost
FROM t2 a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t1_fk, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM t2
    GROUP BY t1_fk
) b
    ON a.t1_fk = b.t1_fk AND a.id = b.max_id;
```

Comment: Is it possible to add all the rows from `t1` into this query.

Comment: Yes, just join to the first table.  I won't edit my answer, because this request was not part of your original question.